# split a BGR matrix without use split() function

Tags: opencv, split, bgr

I am programming with Visual Studio 2012 and the Opencv library, in the 2.4.6 version.

Someone can help me about splitting a BGR image into three images, one for every channel?

I know that there is the split function in OpenCV, but it causes me an unhandled exception, probably because I have a 64 bit processor with the 32 bit library, or probably it's the version of the library, so I want to know how to iterate on the pixel values of a BGR matrix without use split().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A better solution would be to use `split()` and fix your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use split() then you can read each r,g,b  pixel value from your source image and write to destination image and which should be single channel.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main( int argc, const char** argv ){

 Mat src = imread("ball.jpg", 1);
 Mat r(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1);
 Mat g(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1);
 Mat b(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1);

 for(int i=0;i<src.rows;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<src.cols;j++){
    Vec3b pixel = src.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
    b.at<uchar>(i,j) = pixel[0];
    g.at<uchar>(i,j) = pixel[1];
    r.at<uchar>(i,j) = pixel[2];
   }
  }

  imshow("src", src);
  imshow("r", r);
  imshow("g", g);
  imshow("b", b);

  waitKey(0);
 }
```